EventBridge listen to multiple s3 buckets
Below is fragment of eventBridge.tf which is configuring event bridge to notify my service about object addition:
...
  rules = {
    s3ObjCreatedEvents = {
      description   = "Capture S3 ObjectCreated events"
      event_pattern = jsonencode(
        {
          "source" : ["aws.s3"],
          "detail-type" : ["Object Created"],
          "detail" : {
            "bucket" : {
              "name" : ["dest-bucket"]
            }
          }
        }
      )
      enabled = true
    }
  }


  targets = {
    s3ObjCreatedEvents = [
      {
        name            = "send-events-to-dest"
        destination     = "dest"
        attach_role_arn = true
      }
    ]
  }

  api_destinations = {
    dest = {
      description                      = "Event consumer endpoint"
      invocation_endpoint              = "http://host.docker.internal:9797/api/v1/notification"
      http_method                      = "POST"
      invocation_rate_limit_per_second = 200
    }
  }
...

it is working perfectly fine.
Now i need to have exactly the same for another bucket.
what i have tried:
"detail" : {
            "bucket" : {
              "name" : ["dest-bucket", **"second-dest-bucket"**]
            }
          }

but it is not working.
I have verified both of buckets existing and files are successfully uploaded to both.
Thanks.

What does "it is not working" mean? Are there any errors? Whee is the "detail" coming from? Any code that could help with reproducing the problem should be added to the question.
